# Evaluate expression given as String

Tags: java

I got some values like this in a string:

```
( 1 or 0 or 1 ) and ( 0 or 1 ) and ( 1 and 1 ) and 1
```

for easier understanding:

```
( true || false || true ) && ( false || true ) && ( true && true ) && true
```

The entire string now evaluates to "true" (1), but how do I check this in a program?
Is there some mathematical calculation I can do to get the result as "1" or "0"?
The string is not fixed. It can change.
If anyone has any idea about how to do this please share.

It's just like the IF statement where you check a certain condition for true or false.

Something like:

```
class TF{
public static void main(String args[]){
int a=5;
int b=10;
int c=5;
if( ( a==c || a==b || a==c ) && ( b==c || a==c ) && ( a==c && c==a ) && a==c ){ System.out.println("true"); }else{ System.out.println("false"); }
} }
```

Similarly, all the below will be "false":

```
( true && false && true ) && ( false || true ) && ( true && true ) && true

( true || false || true ) && ( false || false ) && ( true && true ) && true

( true || false || true ) && ( false || true ) && ( true && true ) && false
```

Comment: You need a parser imho.

Comment: You can split your String at `&&` and think of a RegEx for each part. Is the structure of the expression always the same or can it be different?

Comment: The structure can change. It can be ( true && true ) || (true && true) which also becomes "true". It's just like the "IF" statement we use in coding. Anything goes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Expression evaluation method. 
To understand method, Refer: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expression-evaluation/

If you don't want to implement this complex method by yourself, You can use library for that. Link to library: https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx

Comment: The EvalEx lib sounds very interesting.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking into this. I think this will work